# HTML: dynamic positioning of overlay to center of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't manage to dynamically position an overlay over an existing resizable textarea element.
Textarea doesn't seem to allow child nodes inside of itself so I have to create it as independent element

```
<body>
  <textarea name="description" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
  <div class="overlay" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">Something to show over the center of textarea</div>
</body>
```

I need to position the overlay element exactly to the middle, while adjusting it's position if the textarea size is adjusted.
Probably I could achieve this by adding size change handlers to the TA and recompute the overlay position each time, but this seems yet too cumbersome to me. Are there any other working, more straightforward methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can pull this off with zero javascript by putting the textarea inside a parent element. In this example, I use a div. Make the parent div resizable and stretch the textarea to fill the entire parent div. Then just using relative positioning, you can position another element on top of the textarea directly in the center of the parent div.

```css
.parent
{
resize: both;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

textarea
{
resize: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #eee;
}

.parent .overlay
{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -50px;
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 35px 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="overlay">Overlay</div>
</div>
```